# My nested if statement seems to be ending my for loop when I want it to continue

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to create a dictionary by mapping keys which increment to a string of the lines in a file.  I need to evaluate if the line has a specific string: "" and then go back to the for loop and continue creating a string for the value in the dictionary.

```
fin = open('test_text_document.txt')
document_1 = ''
dictionary_1 = {}
dictionary_reference = 0
for line in fin:
    document_1 = document_1 + str(line)
    if '"<NEW DOCUMENT>"\n' in line:
        dictionary_1[dictionary_reference + 1] = document_1
         document_1 = ''
```

All that will print when I check dictionary_1 though is the first document key to value pair.  Is my if statement stopping my for loop?

Comment: What's in the first few lines of the file? Also, your `if` statement's string actually contains the double quotes in the string. Was that deliberate?

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't stop the `for` loop; I guess the problem would be at `'"<NEW DOCUMENT>"\n'` string

Comment: Are you getting an error? Your indentation, as posted, is off.

Comment: The double quotes was deliberate.  I indented wrong on my post, not  actually in my code, I'm not getting an indentation error.  The first couple of lines are just straightforward sentences pulled from a news article.

Answer (score 3):

You're not incrementing the key value.  You're just assigning the value of 1 to your key.

Set up a counter after setting the value to your key and it will work as expected.

```
dictionary_1[dictionary_reference] = document_1
dictionary_reference = dictionary_reference + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I set up the new code but I'm actually still just getting one dictionary entry, I should be getting a second.  I get a keyerror when asking for dictionary_1[2] so I figure it just is not making it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the file, it might be simpler to read it all into memory, and call `split` to break it up into separate documents:

```
with open('test_text_document.txt') as infile:
    content = infile.read()
    documents = content.split('"<NEW_DOCUMENT>"')
```

Note that `split` will return a list instead of a dict, which is different than your original code but seems to match how you'd like to access the documents anyway. If you do in fact need a dict, you could get one with this:

```
d = {i:v for i, v in enumerate(documents)}
```